# Small idea for a Crossword Puzzle

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Williams given usual covers. (5)
>   4. Aromatic resin vehicle has speed zero. (7)
>   8. Increase in Zimbabwean dance music leads to extra rain from God of thunder. (7)
>   9. Concealed in derelict antique. (5)
>   10. Short as lettuce. (3)
>   12. Water tank's bluish-green drink contains iodine. (8)
>   13. Yellow bus driver got towed, in part. (4)
>   14. All points used to stitch. (4)
>   15. Movie ends with alien encounter. (4)
>   18. The outdoors has nothing to enclose. (4)
>   20. Argue endlessly about tomato sauce. (4)
>   23. Wax clean before day's end. (4)
>   25. Mesh latch for jam. (8)
>   27. We object to a New World. (3)
>   28. Complete issue. (5)
>   29. Most aristocratic snob let out. (7)
>   30. New York City, over there, has a king for five hundred seconds. (7)
>   31. Soil tossed at her. (5)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Mythical weapon has velocity to half-open door badly. (5)
>   2. South Australian islands originally known by quiet melody. (7)
>   3. Awkwardly runs at sci-fi awards ceremony. (6)
>   4. Oxford station where clouds with rain start to become cold. (6)
>   5. Disfigures broken arms. (4)
>   6. Composer of eight answers? (5)
>   7. Company involved in radar beacon for American mammal. (7)
>   11. Getting elusive fish back is a sign. (4)
>   13. Peace activist Bono bowled out. (3)
>   15. Freddie is happy about copper. (7)
>   16. Five points for effort? (3)
>   17. Encourages, for example, Gauss to strike. (4)
>   19. Raised structure houses single trailblazer. (7)
>   21. Sounds like you raced alongside American God. (6)
>   22. I bleed fudge that can be eaten. (6)
>   24. Prohibition about to stick in relay. (5)
>   26. A thousand carve sailing boat. (5)
>   27. Sudden rush removes small desire. (4)

This is my first cryptic crossword so constructive feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Wordplay explanations, with thanks to jafe for pointing out something important that I'd missed:

> 1a. substring. 4a. CAR containing MPH O. 8a. UP in JIT + E(-xtra) R(-ain). 9a. substring. 10a. COS is shortening of BECAUSE.
>  12a. AQUA + RUM containing I.
>  13a. substring. 14a. (NSEW)*. 15a. M(-ovi)E + ET. 18a. O + PEN. 20a. (ARGU(-e))*.
>  23a. RUB + (-da)Y. 25a. GRID+LOCK. 27a. US (accusative of WE) + A. 28a. double def. 29a. SNOBLET*.
>  30a. YON(D->K)ER + S. 31a. ATHER*.
>  1d. V + AJAR*. 2d. NE + P + TUNE. 3d. RUNSAT*. 6d. Holst composed *The Planets*, whose eight names are in the grid. (Holst's piece only has seven of them, since it doesn't count EARTH.) 7d. CO in RACON. 11d. NEMO<. 13d. (-b)ONO.
>  15d. CU in MERRY. 16d. double def. 17d. EG + G + S. 19d PIER containing ONE.
>  21d. U + RAN + US. 22d. IBLEED*. 24d. BAN about TO. 26d. K + ETCH. 27d. (-s)URGE.

And -- as jafe noticed, and I'm mortified that I didn't --

> 6d points out a theme here: either of the answers are names of planets in our solar system.

Some feedback as requested:

> JIT in 8a is pretty damn obscure.
>  I like the misdirection in 13a where the bus driver, not the bus, is yellow.
>  14a seems to have the wrong tense.
>  18a is a nice find.
>  In 20a the def seems slightly out; surely a ragu is, importantly, a *meat and tomato* sauce.
>  In 25a, the wordplay is a bit too close semantically to the actual answer -- "gridlock" really is grid + lock, the grid in question really is a mesh, and the lock in question really is a jam. (We even use the term "traffic jam".)
>  I like the misdirection in 30a, where "New York City" means *a* city in New York State but not NYC.
>  1d is an indirect anagram. You're not meant to do that. Also, "ajar" doesn't mean "half-open door", it means "half-open".
>  I'm not sure that "Oxford station" can validly define CIRCUS in 4d, even though there is indeed a (London) train station called "Oxford Circus".
>  I'm not keen on "getting" in 11d. Also, while indeed the movie was called "Finding Nemo", IIRC it's not that Nemo was *elusive*, it's that he had been *captured*, which is kinda different.
>  One of the defs in 16d is a little iffy; a try *scores* five points but it's not true that it *is* five points.
>  I'm not totally convinced by the def in 17d; to *egg on* is to encourage, but I'm not sure that to *egg* is.
>  In 21d, "Sounds like U" is an *adjectival phrase that describes* `U` rather than a *definition* of it, which is a little naughty, though this is a fairly common variety of naughtiness.

(Note: for hopefully-obvious reasons most of the feedback is critical; that doesn't mean this was a bad puzzle; it was fun.)

Comment: In 6d, surely it's "eight [of the] answers"?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, this is very helpful, I will keep these points in mind for the next time. jafe is right about the interpretation of 6d. Part of my motivation was getting them all in there. I'm a little embarrassed about 14a, not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: Oh! I am a moron and therefore completely didn't notice what jafe points out, which is super-embarrassing.

Comment: Answer amended appropriately. Apologies!